# How to kill specific Find command?

Tags: bash, scripts

The specific find command I am trying to kill is running inside of a user created script?

I created a script that inside of it, it contains a find command that runs for up to 10 minutes, before I run that same script again, it needs to kill that find command.

Comment: `pkill`/`killall`, or `pgrep`/`pidof`+`kill`

Answer (score 1):

#### pgrep

You can use `pgrep` with `-a` switch:

```
pgrep -a find
```

it will give you a full command line as well as the process ID:

```
10838 find / -iname png
10839 find / -iname jpg
```

then you can decide if it's the one you want to kill or not:

```
kill 10838
```

will kill the png one.

#### pkill

you can also use `pkill` like this:

```
pkill -x "find / -iname png"
```

`-x` means: Only match processes whose names.

#### Find child process:

use tree to find your desired process, let's say your script name is "script.sh" you can use `pgrep -f script` to find it, then pass the output to `pstree` to get a list of it's child and kill the find process which is the child of your script.

```
$ pstree -p $(pgrep -f script)
bash(10915)───find(10916)
$ kill 10916
```

Comment: `-x`/`--exact` is used to perform exact matches. What you're looking for is `-f`/`--full` to take the entire command-line into account and not just the executable name. For the last variant you may also find `-P`/`--parent` useful.